# How to conditionally drag and drop a div

Tags: jquery

When moving a div from **FIRST** to **Second**

I need to check if this div already exists inside **Second**

(based on the tag-id="2" video-id="4" attributes)

i have tried it this way

During the drag and drop inside the stop callback function

I am trying to fetch the tag-id

but i am geting the following error

VM317:95Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).closest is not a function

```
var PortletDraggable = function () {

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            if (!jQuery().sortable) {
                return;
            }

            $("#sortable_portlets").sortable({
                connectWith: ".portlet",
                items: ".portlet", 
                opacity: 0.8,
                handle : '.portlet-title',
                coneHelperSize: true,
                placeholder: 'portlet-sortable-placeholder',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                tolerance: "pointer",
                helper: "clone",
                tolerance: "pointer",
                forcePlaceholderSize: !0,
                helper: "clone",
                cancel: ".portlet-sortable-empty, .portlet-fullscreen", // cancel dragging if portlet is in fullscreen mode
                revert: 250, // animation in milliseconds
                update: function(b, c) {
                    if (c.item.prev().hasClass("portlet-sortable-empty")) {
                        c.item.prev().before(c.item);
                    }   
                },


                stop: function(event, ui) {

                              console.log($(event.target).attr('id').closest('packlistupdate').attr('tag-id'));

                        }


            });
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    PortletDraggable.init();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33keyjxx/22/

Could you please let em know how to conditionally drag and drop a div ?

Comment: is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 'ui' instead of the 'event' , Here is the [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf43wd/)

below changes need in your stop function:

```
  stop: function(event, ui) {
                                    debugger;
                    console.log($(ui.item).attr('tag-id'));
                    console.log($(ui.item).attr('video-id'));
                                }
```

I hope this solution is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to use `find()` to traverse inside droppable div . `closest()` will traverse to check the parent starting from itself
- And some code change :)

  `console.log($(event.target).find('.packlistupdate').attr('tag-id'));`

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/33keyjxx/23/)